# C pointers not being recognized by printf

Tags: c

I am trying to build a simple C application testing pointers. There is no output, however, and I am unsure why.

```
void printSummary(int *a, float *b, char *c[]) {
    printf("Summary: \n  A: %d\n  B: %.1f\n  C: %s\n", *a, *b, *c);
}

int pointersChanging () {
    // init variables
    int a    = 10;
    float b  = 20.0;
    char c[] = "Hello, World!";

    // Init pointer variables
    int *p1 = &a;
    float *p2 = &b;
    char *p3[strlen(c)]; /* init new char sequence using the length of c */

    strcpy( *p3, c); /* copy c into *p3 (the value of p3) */

    printSummary(p1,p2,p3);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    pointersChanging();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My bad, I should have explained. It simply calls the pointersChanging function

Comment: `p3` is array of `strlen(c)` pointers, why you need that ? Single char pointer is enough to point to `c`.

Comment: `char *p3[strlen(c)];` is an array of pointers. `*p3` (same as `p3[0]`) is a unitialized pointer. You cannot `strcpy()` into it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your actual code is including?

Comment: `char *p3[strlen(c)];` is an array of `strlen(c)` pointers to char.  To declare it as an array of `strlen(c)` chars, you must declare it as `char p3[strlen(c);` or simply as `char *p3 = malloc(strlen(c)+1); /* don't forget the null, nor free(p3)ing at the end */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `p3` as an array of *pointers* instead of an array of characters.  You then pass `*p3` to `strcpy` which is an uninitialized pointer, which then attempts to dereference the invalid pointer invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You also haven't given `p3` space for the null byte at the end of the string `c`.

Change `p3` to a `char` array and give it an extra byte of space:

```
char p3[strlen(c)+1];
strcpy( p3, c);
```

And change `printSummary` to match:

```
void printSummary(int *a, float *b, char c[]) {
    printf("Summary: \n  A: %d\n  B: %.1f\n  C: %s\n", *a, *b, c);
}
```

Comment: This works, but the point of the p3 variable was to use a pointer variable in this context. The code you suggested just removes the pointer element from the p3 variable, essentially making it just the c variable.

Comment: @RyanCocuzzo Then you don't need an array at all.  Just declare `p3` as a pointer: `char *p3 = c;`.

Comment: That yields the output: `Summary: 
  A: 10`